# Burnside's lemma simple use

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, group-actions, necklace-and-bracelets

Let's say that $D_3$ acts on a bracelet of 3 beads (Denote S), 
each bead can be Black or White.
I want to count the number of different bracelets (4 - I believe)

But using burnside's lemma I get something else...
What am I doing wrong?

$R$ := reflection,
$S$ := Spin clockwise "vertex to vertex"

$|Orb(S)| = \frac{1}{|D_3|}   \sum_{x \in D_3} |Fix(x)| =  \frac{1}{6} (|Fix(Id)|+|Fix(R)|+|Fix(S)|+|Fix(S^2)|+|Fix(RS)|+|Fix(RS^2)|)  = \frac{1}{6} (8+4+2+2+2+2) \notin \mathbb{Z}  $

---

I have found the problem simple calculation mistake, thanks.
$|Fix(RS)| = |Fix(RS^2)| = 4$

non trivial at first were:

$RS(BBW) = R(WBB) = BBW$

$RS^2 (WBB) = RS(BWB) = R(BBW) = WBB$

Answer (score 2):

This is easier (for me, at least) to do in terms of permutations of the vertices, where we have the following fixed point counts:
$$123:\ 8$$
$$213:\ 4\mbox{ color scheme AAB}$$
$$132:\ 4\mbox{ color scheme ABB}$$
$$312:\ 2\mbox{ color scheme AAA}$$
$$231:\ 2\mbox{ color scheme AAA}$$
$$321:\ 4\mbox{ color scheme ABA}$$
This gives 4 bracelets.